# Getting the file extension of a filename in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, string, file-extension

How can I get the file extension of a filename in VB.NET? Let's say that my string is `"Jim.jpg"`. I want to get `".jpg"`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would use a combination of IndexOf and Substring, but in this particular case there is a better option.

Take a look at System.IO.Path. It has methods specifically for breaking a filename into parts.